# css sprite button is jumping around

Tags: css, css-sprites

Does anyone know what is causing the sprite rollover to jump around

It is I think more likely a photoshop question, but I am not completely sure.
I hope to get an answer here anyway, since I think most webdesigners/programmers problably worked with photoshop also.

This is what I want the rollover to do **[example 1](http://pgdegans.webfactional.com/)**

and this is **[my testpage](http://taxi-bel.nl/account/afspeellijst)** (see the play button)

*I made the sprite with spriteme.com*

thanks, Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see anything jumping around. However, when I first open the page the Play button is missing (its style is set to display: none;).  When I click stop it appears, and then disappears when I click play.  This is due to it's inline "display" style being set to block and none.

Is this your problem?

Note: I tested in Chrome and FF.  I debugged the CSS states using Firebug.

Comment: As you can see from the first example the buttoncolor rollover is flawless, but mine is shifting out off place? Sofar, I only did a sprite on the play button. The play button rollover states are vissible when the stop button is pushed. That is intentionally done.

Comment: With photoshop, I only did a 40px rounded rectangle, trimmed it and saved it for web. With color overlay, I changed the color.

Comment: What browser are you using? With Chrome and FF I see no jerking at all.  It is the Play button that you have an issue with isnt it?

Comment: I use FF. Don't you see a slight shifting when you hover over the play button?

Comment: No I don't, however, the change in contrast / colour between the dark grey and the orange does make you think the white triangle is changing size, but that is just an optical illusion.  I am using FF 3.6.3 btw

Comment: Maybe, but I don't think so, because I am not seeing it in the first example.

Comment: I changed the hover state to blue, and it does look better, so maybe your right. I just can't believe it. It's a pain if I can't use that color. I will try some other combinations with less contrast or whatever then.